# Unit testing dynamic class load

Tags: java, unit-testing, dynamic, reflection, groovy

I have a simple pattern for a dynamic factory in Java (groovy actually but for all purposes we can assume is java) which receives an operation and dynamically loads a handler for that specific operation by reading it from a property file with the corresponding name.

The pattern is as simple as having a base method with the following signature:

```
class ReflectionFactory implements BaseFactory {

   PropertyReader propertyReader

   public ReflectionFactory(PropertyReader reader) {
      this.propertyReader = reader
   }

   Adapter resolveAdapter(String serviceName) {
    // TODO: Find service configuration in propertyReader and load via class loader
      return defaultAdapter
   }
}
```

The functionality in the class is not yet implemented and I want to implement it using TDD, that is, I want to create a test that will verify that, given a *serviceName*, it will return a class of the appropriate type.

The code that will load the class will be similar to:

```
String className = propertyReader.getProperty(serviceName)
this.class.classLoader.loadClass(className, true, false)
```

The way I see it, I need to "mock" the class loader, but obviously I don't want to introduce an injected class just to replace this line:

```
this.class.classLoader.loadClass(className, true, false)
```

Is there any way to test that the classLoader is being invoked with the right parameters? In other words, is there a way to "mock" or "replace" invocation of the classLoader?

Ideally I would be able to do (pseudocode)

```
when(classLoader.loadClass("serviceName", true, false)).thenReturn(dummyClassInstance)
```

So the test code will look something like:

```
void testWhenResolveServiceAndClassPropertyDefinedInstansceIsCreated() {

  serviceName = "myService"
  when(propertyReader.getPropertyValue("myService")).thenReturn("com.mydomain.adapters.testAdapter")
  when(classLoader.loadClass("com.mydomain.adapters.testAdapter", true, false)).thenReturn(testDummy)

  def factory = new ReflectionFactory(propertyReader)
  def adapter = factory.resolveAdapter(serviceName)

  assertNotNull(adapter)
  verify(classloader).loadClass("com.mydomain.adapters.testAdapter", true, false)
}
```

I'm using Mockito as a mocking framework but any mocking framework / solution is welcome

Comment: Before I try, could You please provide full - sample implementation of ReflectionFactory and test (with when, then)? Might be not compiling and not working as well - just want to catch the whole picture.

Comment: Implementation is as I defined, that is, the functionality has not been implemented yet. Have a look at the edited question for details about the test I want to write

Comment: Thanks, will try it at evening UTC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood well I can suggest something like that (test is written in spock framework):

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
   def 'test'() {
      given:
      def propertyReader = GroovyMock(PropertyReader)
      def loader = GroovyMock(ClassLoader)        

      and:
      def serviceName = 'service'
      def serviceClass = 'service.class'
      def adapter = new Adapter()

      and:
      def factory = new ReflectionFactory()
      factory.propertyReader = propertyReader
      factory.loader = loader

      when:
      def ret = factory.resolveAdapter(serviceName)

      then:
      ret == adapter
      1 * propertyReader.findProperty(serviceName) >> serviceClass
      1 * loader.loadClass('service.class', true, false) >> adapter
   }
}

class ReflectionFactory {

   PropertyReader propertyReader
   ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader()

   Adapter resolveAdapter(String serviceName) {
      def cls = propertyReader.findProperty(serviceName)
      loader.loadClass(cls, true, false)
   }
}

class PropertyReader {
    String findProperty(String name) {
        //some logic here
    }
}

class Adapter {}
```

Hope it helps You somehow.

Comment: Is that what You were looking for?